# weight issues in scikit-learn's adaboost

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use AdaBoostClassifier with a decision tree stump as the base classifier. I noticed that the weight adjustment done by AdaBoostClassifier has been giving me errors both for SAMME.R and SAMME options.

Here's a brief overview of what I'm doing

```
def train_adaboost(features, labels):
    uniqLabels = np.unique(labels)
    allLearners = []
    for targetLab in uniqLabels:
        runs=[]
        for rrr in xrange(10):
            feats,labs = get_binary_sets(features, labels, targetLab)
            baseClf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1, min_samples_leaf=1)
            baseClf.fit(feats, labs)

            ada_real = AdaBoostClassifier( base_estimator=baseClf, 
                                           learning_rate=1, 
                                           n_estimators=20, 
                                           algorithm="SAMME")
            runs.append(ada_real.fit(feats, labs))
        allLearners.append(runs)

    return allLearners
```

I looked at the fit for every single decision tree classifier and they are able to predict some labels.
When I look at the AdaBoostClassifier using this base classifier, however, I get errors about the weight boosting algorithm.

```
def compute_confidence(allLearners, dada, labbo):
    for ii,thisLab in enumerate(allLearners):
        for jj, thisLearner in enumerate(thisLab):
            #accessing thisLearner's methods here
```

The methods give errors like these:

`ipdb> thisLearner.predict_proba(myData)`

`PATHTOPACKAGE/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py:727: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  proba /= self.estimator_weights_.sum()
*** ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds`

`ipdb> thisLearner.predict(myData)`

`PATHTOPACKAGE/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py:639: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  pred /= self.estimator_weights_.sum()
*** IndexError: 0-d arrays can only use a single () or a list of newaxes (and a single ...) as an index`

I tried SAMME.R algorithm for adaboost but I can't even fit adaboost in that case because of this error
`[...]`

`File "PATH/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py", line 388, in fit
    return super(AdaBoostClassifier, self).fit(X, y, sample_weight)`

`File "PATH/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py", line 124, in fit
    X_argsorted=X_argsorted)`

`File "PATH/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py", line 435, in _boost
    X_argsorted=X_argsorted)`

`File "PATH/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py", line 498, in _boost_real
    (estimator_weight < 0)))`

`ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1000) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1000,1000)`

the data's dimensions are actually compatible with the format that classifier is expecting, both before using adaboost and when I try to test the trained classifiers. What can these errors indicate?

Comment: Could you describe what is `myData` in terms of type (array or list?), dtype, shape.

Comment: Certainly. In the case where I was getting these errors, the types, dtype, and shape were like these for myData( used as feats below) and labs. 

For feats: dtype('float64'), <type 'numpy.ndarray'>, (1000, 20)
For labs: dtype('int8'), <type 'numpy.ndarray'>, (1000, 1). 

The solution was trivial to the problem (I wrote an answer below), I just wasn't familiar with python's array shapes.

Answer (score 2):

Well that was a little counterintuitive, coming from coding in Matlab.

Apparently the labs' dimensions was the issue, which is (1000,1). It needed to be (1000,)

Adding this line solved it:

labs = labs[:,0]